# Update XML value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Hopefully, someone can help.

I have a SQL Server table with a column `StudentMessage` which contains XML:

```
<StudentMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0">
  <ProcessHeader xmlns="">
  ..
  </ProcessHeader>
  <Student xmlns="">
    <StudentRegNo>550059513</StudentRegNo>
    <TypeOfStudent>A</TypeOfStudent>
    ..
    ..
  </Student>
  ..
</StudentMessage>
```

I'm trying to update the value in `TypeOfStudent` from A to B.

I initially tried the below which was accepted however the value wasn't updated which lead me to believe I have the XPATH incorrect

```
UPDATE [Student]
SET StudentMessage.modify('replace value of (//*:StudentMessage/*:Student[1]/@TypeOfStudent)[1] with ("B")')
WHERE StudentMessageId = 19181
```

The full XPATH of `TypeOfStudent` is below:

```
/*[local-name()='StudentMessage' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0']/*[local-name()='Student' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='TypeOfStudent' and namespace-uri()='']
```

I also tried using

```
UPDATE [Student]
SET StudentMessage.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()='StudentMessage' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0']/*[local-name()='Student' and namespace-uri()='']/@*[local-name()='TypeOfStudent' and namespace-uri()=''])[1] with ("B")')
WHERE StudentMessageId = 19181
```

and again it doesn't update.

For this purpose, the tbl `Student` contains 2 columns

```
StudentMessageId (INT) 
StudentMessage (XML)
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the docs? This might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/openxml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `with xmlnamespaces ('http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0' AS sm)`, and then the node to be replaced can be referred to as `(sm:StudentMessage/Student/TypeOfStudent/text())[1]`. It's likely that the `Student` and `TypeOfStudent` nodes ending up in the empty namespace is actually an error and they should have been in the parent namespace, but there you go.

Comment: `… /*:Student[1]/TypeOfStudent/text())[1] with …`

Answer (score 2):

You should use proper namespace aliasing for this. Also you need to get the `text()` node, and you need to check it is not already `"A"`

You can use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to declare a namespace alias.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0' AS ns
)
UPDATE Student
SET StudentMessage.modify('
    replace value of (ns:StudentMessage/Student/TypeOfStudent/text()[. = "A"])[1]
    with "B"
'
)
WHERE StudentMessage.exist('ns:StudentMessage/Student/TypeOfStudent/text()[. = "A"]') = 1
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85d53cb0bd290457a841397e4294cd00)

Alternatively declare it inline in the XQuery

```sql
UPDATE Student
SET StudentMessage.modify('
    declare namespace ns = "http://example.com/ESB/Schemas/Canonical/StudentMessage/1.0";
    replace value of (ns:StudentMessage/Student/TypeOfStudent/text()[. = "A"])[1]
    with "B"
'
)
WHERE StudentMessage.exist('ns:StudentMessage/Student/TypeOfStudent/text()[. = "A"]') = 1;

SELECT * FROM Student;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=352b2f5fa7990a3619de72f092daffa4)